# How to write initbinder for json deserialization?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, deserialization, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have the following POJO:

```
class MyClass{
    ...
    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK //from org.springframework.http
    @JsonIgnore
    public HttpStatus getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
     }

    @JsonProperty(value = "HttpStatus")
    public void setHttpStatus(HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }
    ....
}
```

When I accept(construct) object from form to correct convert String to HttpStatus I have wrote `InitBinder`:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(HttpStatus.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        public void setAsText(String code) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(code)) {
                setValue(HttpStatus.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(code)));
            }
        }
    });
```

For form it works cool.

I also have controller method which accepts json:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "sendData.json", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void putJsonData(@RequestBody MyClass myClass) {
        ....
    }
```

I pass httpStatus like this:

```
...
"HttpStatus":500
...
```

but it converts incorrect and I see following error message:

```
Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.HttpStatus from number value (500): index value outside legal index range [0..65]\n
```

As I understand it converts incorrect.

How can I customize this process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was resolved like this:

```
class MyClass{
    ...
    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK //from org.springframework.http
    @JsonIgnore
    public HttpStatus getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
     }

    @JsonProperty(value = "HttpStatus")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = HttpStatusDeserializer.class)
    public void setHttpStatus(HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }
    ....
}
```

and deserializer:

```
public class HttpStatusDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<HttpStatus> {    
    @Override
    public HttpStatus deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        return HttpStatus.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(node.asText()));
    }
}
```